# Why does changing the image size in css grid create padding?

Tags: html, css, grid

im creating portfolio and i have projects section there. I have image css grid, it working but images are too big[image: big image css grid] so i want them smaller, but when i change max-width or set width on image lower it create padding [image: smaller image grid with padding] , how can i solve it? I dont want there the padding between images in grid.
Thanks for any advice!

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
}

.mygrid img {
  max-width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
        <div class="mygrid mt-6">
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
        </div>
```

Comment: change the 1fr to auto in the column setting ?

Comment: thanks for advice but its not working :/

Comment: with that, add justify-content:center?

Comment: still no changes

Comment: Include images in your code, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by include? web1.jpg is just random 1024x1024 image from google

Comment: Could you provide the URL for `web1.jpg` then so we can turn this into a code snippet?

Comment: https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp4471413.jpg you can use this for example, its have the same res like my picture i cant find url

Comment: I mean add actual images to your code so we can reproduce the problem. placekitten.com is one option. lorempixel.com and placeholder.com, are two others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `75%` it means you will have `25%` of free space whatever the configuration so don't play with the image size. Adjust the column size:

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 25%); /* adjust here */
  justify-content: center;
}

.mygrid img {
  max-width: 100%; /* keep 100% here */
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid mt-6">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="Sample photo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);`, you can use `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, fit-content(100%));` so that each column is fit to the image size.

Comment: its not working in my case, i also tried applied this on grid-template-rows